# Is it a bug or typo in mysql_com.h header file on line 320?

Tags: mysql, visual-c++

When I'm trying to connect to MySQL, visual studio complains about missing semi colon:

```
c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.6\include\mysql_com.h(320):
    error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'fd'

c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.6\include\mysql_com.h(320):
    error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
    support default-int
```

Then I check on that exact line, and there's written:

```
my_socket fd;                   /* For Perl DBI/dbd */
```

`my_socket` is marked red in `mysql_com.h` file. Is it a bug or something?

Comment: Above where you include the mysql headers, try adding `#define my_socket SOCKET` and also make sure you include `<winsock.h>`.